# How to implement ontology in chatbots?

Tags: nlp, ontology, text-analysis

I am trying to develop a chatbot that needs to have a basic ontology embedded in it. I'm having trouble thinking of an approach to solve these kinds of problem.

For example,

```
User Input: Who is Barack Obama?
Answer: Barack Obama is a politician of the USA.

User Input: What is his age?
Answer: 57 years.
```

What should I do to let the system know `his` in the second question refers to `Barack Obama` in the first question? Thanks.

Comment: This is called coreference see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreference